# Firebase events are missing "device.advertising_id" in BigQuery

Tags: android, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have multiple Android-only apps utilizing a shared codebase with different flavors.  Each of these apps report events to Firebase which I can query in BigQuery.  All of the apps should be reporting the standard demographic data (including AdvertisingID) however currently two are not showing the "device.advertising_id" (nor "device.vendor_id") in BigQuery when I view the events.  All of the apps (including those not reporting advertising_id) are reporting other device demographic data like device brand/model, OS version, language and timezone offset as well as custom user properties.

I do not have flavor-specific configurations or code to limit access to firebase analytics.  I do not set "google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" in the manifest anywhere, nor do I use the "FirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled()" method in the codebase.  I do not see any configuration in the Firebase console to limit a particular app reporting the advertising ID.  All apps include the firebase plugin and google play services libraries.

Everything between the apps seems to be the same and the data reported is the same except for the "device.advertising_id" not showing up for two of them.

Any ideas why the advertising ID is not being reported?

Answer (score 2):

The issue ended up being in the Firebase link to BigQuery.  When you configure the link (in Firebase > Project > Settings > Integrations > BigQuery) you have to enable "Include Advertising Identifiers in Export".